# Does/Will Rust support functional programming idioms?

Tags: functional-programming, rust

I love the fact that Rust supports algebraic data types and in particular matching of those,
but are there any plans to support other functional idioms?

1. E.g. is there a collection of the standard filter/map/reduce functions in the standard library, and more important, can you chain/compose them in a syntactical pleasing manner [1]?
2. Since there are already elegant means for ADTs to be used, how about monads, in particular some syntactic sugar for them?

[1] Haskell got (.) and (>>>), C# extension methods and optionally LINQ, D has unified function call syntax.

Comment: Check out this macro that can derive HKT: https://gist.github.com/14427/af90a21b917d2892eace

Comment: That's impressive! Although the naming of the type variables seems rather arbitrary. I didn't even know that you could have traits with type variables. This is an excellent hack.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Rust doesn't have HKT's, but its iterators *do* support coding in a functional style with higher order functions (HOF) like `map`, `filter`, `fold` etc., with convenient chaining.

The details differ compared to functional languages- those are usually garbage collected, whereas Rust programs deal with memory management in a deterministic manner, similar to C++ RAII - as part of the program's flow.

To allow efficient chaining, the individual HOF's return composable lazy expression templates, and you can turn the final result into data (allocating and evaluating in one step) by finishing with `.to_owned_vec()` or `.collect()` or whatever.

In some situations this isn't necessary, the expression-template returned is an iterator itself and that might be sufficient. For example, you can iterate over that with a `for` loop, or pass it as an argument to a generic function.

See:

- http://static.rust-lang.org/doc/master/std/iter/index.html
- http://static.rust-lang.org/doc/master/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html

Similar patterns are possible in both C++11 (with additional libraries) and Rust. Rust's generics aren't quite as powerful as C++ templates, but immutability by default, expression-oriented syntax, polymorphic lambdas, and two-way type inference give it a feel slightly closer to a functional language.

Regarding 'extension methods' and uniform call syntax, Rust allows a similar 'open-world' way of organizing code. You can add `impl`s with more methods to any type anywhere within a library or program, or extend existing types from other libraries by implementing your own trait's methods on them.

This makes it easier to use the chainable method calling style than in C++ (i.e. less need to modify or derive types).

Bear in mind a lot of Haskell's idioms are to do with purity (e.g. the IO monad, lenses..), and Rust is multi-paradigm, not pure-functional. You can have a pure function for the benefits of referential transparency at the program level, and yet its implementation is simplified by mutable local variables.

Comment: This is informative and complements the other answer. But doesn't using traits mean that you introduce runtime polymorphism and potential un-inlineability compared to D? I see that you can avoid it with expression templates (neat!), but if I could use traits for the same code, it would be even more awesome... Anyway, It'd be still superior to C#'s IEnumerable.

Comment: traits are used for both runtime and compile time polymorphism; they are like the proposed C++ concepts (bounding template parameters for better compile-time errors) , or you can instantiate a 'trait-object' in which case the trait is used to format a vtable. Like C++, you only get a vtable if you explicitely ask for it.

Comment: unlike C++, (and like Go) the vtables ptrs are carried with a pointer; the underlying structs do not contain any class information.

Comment: unlike C++, some combitation of traits and methods are required to enable compile-time polymorphism(you can only 'overload' based on the receiver), even if the end result is the same as c++ overloading. This is a design choice on the part of the rust team, regarding how polymorphism is organized/presented. rather than a low-level issue.  Its intended to make  template errors less scary.

Comment: Regarding your last edit about monads: It's just that I found them useful not only for IO stuff, but also for elegantly handling Maybe, Either, etc. And because it's new and hipster to me right now, ofc.

Comment: rust has Option<T> , Either<A,B> and so on and uses those extensively in its standard libraries. generics+ADTs seem to be the pre-requisits. I'm not a FP guru - not entirely sure i could tell you what a monad IS :) but i'm sold on many of these patterns in the forms that they can be retrofitted to C++, and have generally like what i see in FP langauges

Comment: they have the ability to chain conditional extraction of values from 'option' with .unwrap_or() , or iterating over the value (if it exists) .. so you can certainly write elegant expressions where these values are passed along.

Comment: HKT = Higher Kinded Types - in C++ terminology, the ability to pass a template to a template. C++ and haskell can do it; Rust currently can't.

Answer (score 16):

A language must have "higher kinded types" to support concepts like Functors, Applicatives and Monads. In other words the language must be able to abstract over types that are * -> *, or functions from type to type. Rust does not currently support this level of abstraction. It has been [discussed](http://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/1a57pw/haskeller_playing_with_rust_a_question_about/) as a possible future direction, but I would not expect it to be a focus anytime soon.

Comment: Aye, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17054978/composition-operator-and-pipe-forward-operator-in-rust

Comment: C# supports Monads through LINQ. IEnumerable<T> and IObservable<T> are both monadic / linqable. However C# doesn't support higher kinded types so I'm not sure the assertion in this answer is correct. Perhaps you mean something slightly more specific.