# Operator overloading on Box<T> in Rust

Tags: rust

Basically, I want to implement pipeline-operator (binary operator for function application) on `Box<T>` using [Operator overloading](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/trait/ops.html) in Rust.

I understand `Box<T>` is a structure

https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/alloc/boxed.rs.html#175-178

and the below is the code I found here for  `struct Wrapped<T>(T)` that has the pipeline-operator as Shr `>>`.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17111630

```
use std::ops::Shr;

struct Wrapped<T>(T);

impl<A, B, F> Shr<F> for Wrapped<A>
where
    F: FnOnce(A) -> B,
{
    type Output = Wrapped<B>;

    fn shr(self, f: F) -> Wrapped<B> {
        Wrapped(f(self.0))
    }
}

fn main() {
    let string = Wrapped(1) >> (|x| x + 1) >> (|x| 2 * x) >> (|x: i32| x.to_string());
    println!("{}", string.0);
}
// prints `4`
```

Here I want `Box<T>` instead of `Wrapped<T>` for the pipeline-operator.

I also found a code here to overload `Add::add` for `Vector`

https://stackoverflow.com/a/28005283

```
impl<'a, 'b> Add<&'b Vector> for &'a Vector {
    type Output = Vector;

    fn add(self, other: &'b Vector) -> Vector {
        Vector {
            x: self.x + other.x,
            y: self.y + other.y,
        }
    }
}
```

Therefore, I suppose there must be a way to implement pipeline-operator (binary operator for function application) on `Box<T>`.

So far, I did

```
use std::ops::Shr;

impl<A, B, F> Shr<F> for Box<A>
where
    F: FnOnce(A) -> B,
{
    type Output = Box<B>;

    fn shr(self, f: F) -> Box<B> {
        Box::new(f(&self))
    }
}
```

etc. but the code doesn't work.

```rust
error[E0210]: type parameter `A` must be used as the type parameter for some local type (e.g., `MyStruct<A>`)
 --> src/main.rs:6:10
  |
6 |     impl<A, B, F> Shr<F> for Box<A>
  |          ^ type parameter `A` must be used as the type parameter for some local type
  |
  = note: implementing a foreign trait is only possible if at least one of the types for which it is implemented is local
  = note: only traits defined in the current crate can be implemented for a type parameter
```

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=5eb74e35e2b5c23b0ab9ba020f1a7b54

Can you fix the code? Thanks.

Comment: You are trying to implement a foreign trait (`Shr`) for a foreign type (`Box`), which is not allowed in Rust. The reason is that in another module, you could write a similar implementation of `Shr` for `Box` that behaves differently; then, if you imported both modules into a new project, the compiler wouldn't know which implementation to use.

Comment: I'm not sure this is a duplicate, but see [How do I implement a trait I don't own for a type I don't own?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25413201/how-do-i-implement-a-trait-i-dont-own-for-a-type-i-dont-own). Generally, like @Coder-256 said, it's impossible. This is called _coherence_, or _the orphan rule_.

Comment: At the moment, it is not possible to implement a pipe operator in Rust for arbitrary types. You could maybe use a macro, but it seems strictly more difficult/complicated than a wrapper; the wrapper you have in your question is slightly inconvenient, but honestly it's probably the best and simplest solution.

Comment: @Coder-256 "At the moment"? Are there any RFCs, or even suggestions, to disable coherence?

Comment: [See here](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/pipe-results-like-elixir/11175/18) for past discussion specifically about the pipe operator. As for coherence and the orphan rules: everybody hates them, and also everybody hates Rust's aliasing/borrowing rules, and so on and so forth... the point is, you pick Rust if you really care about doing things the *right* way, not the easy way. The rules are annoying but they exist for a reason. Generally, any programming language has to pick 2 out of 3: fast, safe, and easy. Rust picks the first 2.

Comment: Thanks Coder-256 and Chayim Friedman, the fact sounds disappointing but informative..

Comment: It's *good* that this isn't allowed. What would right shift on `Box` even mean? New semantics go into new types. Then you can define shifting in a context where it makes sense.